# can i indepent connect the wlst and use it's function on other script

Tags: python, wlst

I have a script `conn.py`, in the script there is a function named `conn()` use the `connect(username,password,url)`to connect the weblogic domain. And have a script `createServer.py`:

```
__main__: 
    import conn
conn.conn() 
cmo.createServer()
```

and i get error on `createServer()`, it seems auto disconnect()  after i run `conn.conn()`, how can i still use WLST online function by this way?

---------------------my console return -------------

```
starting the script ....
input your user name : weblogic
input your user password : weblogic456
Connecting to t3://localhost:7001 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server 'AdminServer' that belongs to domain 'demo'.

Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the 
server. To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or 
Admin port should be used instead.

connect OK.

You will need to be connected to a running server to execute this command


You will need to be connected to a running server to execute this command

Error: No domain or domain template has been read.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/chopperlee/Program/Workspace/configWL/wlst/createServer.py", line 84, in ?
  File "/home/chopperlee/Program/Workspace/configWL/wlst/createServer.py", line 37, in createServer
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'createServer'
```

Comment: Whats error you got ?

Comment: `You will need to be connected to a running server to execute this command`
and `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'createServer'`
absoultely it disconnect before run the createServer()

Comment: will you please past whole tracktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the createServer.py", line 37, 84 anything missing arguments in it.

Answer (score 0):

The WLST connect function sets some global variables, which in python are in fact global to the module -- in your case, the conn module -- not to the entire python runtime.

So the connect actually works in the context of your conn module. Other WLST commands which depend on - and check for - a connection would probably work if invoked from inside the conn module.

But the globals that record that connection from your conn module are not visible to your main script or to WLST commands invoked from there, so WLST commands that need a connection fail when run from your main script.